# Printing square numbers in Visual Basic using loops

Tags: vb.net, loops, numbers, perfect-square

I'm trying to print a list of square numbers in Visual Basic using a for loop. I'm a newbie, and find this pretty hard. The program I'm writing is supposed to print a list of the squares of numbers e.g. (1, 4, 9, 16, and so on.)

Comment: If this is homework (which it clearly is) please tag it as such. Also, please show what you have already tried. See http://tinyurl.com/so-hints for more suggestions on improving your question.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a counter to your loop then each time the loop is executed increment it. Then inside the loop you would just need to times the counter with itself for the square.

```
square = counter*counter;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   Sub Main()

            For number As Integer = 1 To 1000
                Console.WriteLine("Square of {0} : {1}", number, number * number)
            Next

            Console.ReadKey()

    End Sub
```